# Exception when using application object?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a socket as an application object. Here's the activity's code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = getApplicationContext();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_connect);
    app = (MyApplication) getApplication();
    connectButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.connect_button);
    connectButton.setOnClickListener(connectListener);
    //app.stablishConnection();

}

private OnClickListener connectListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

         app.stablishConnection();  
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShowDetails.class);
         startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

And here is the Application class' code

```
private Socket socket;
Context context;

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
public void onTerminate() {
    super.onTerminate();
}

public void stablishConnection(){
    try {   InetAddress serverAddr;
        serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("10.10.10.10");
        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 5000);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I want the socket not to be destroyed until the application is closed and I want to create the socket once the user click the button.

The system shows me a androidblockguardpolicy exception when the activity calls `app.stablishConnection()`. I've also tried to call this method in onCreate (you can see it commented) and in that case it shows and Unable to start componentInfo exception when the app tries to create the socket `socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 5000);` in the application class.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't perform network operations on the main/UI thread of your application. There are many tutorials out there on creating services or using a background thread / async task to perform any network IO you need to do.

Comment: Should I create a thread in the application class? I'll try it, but I think it only accounts for one of the exception. Is there any troble in calling `app.stablishConnection()` from the OnClickListener?

Comment: I don't think the async task is a good example for long-running network operations. `Service` or `HandlerThread` is the best choice in my opinion.

Comment: @toro, I don't know this persons use case, but you are right that its always dependent on what he is doing.

Comment: @user2071976, The onClickListener is also occurring on the main thread. You can spawn your thread / service / task from that handler if that is the route you decide to go.